# What is a Memory Safety Vulnerability?

Tags: security, memory, memory-management

I'm looking at a competition that is looking for memory safety vulnerability mitigation techniques. I did a bit of research, but I wasn't able to come up with what exactly a memory safety vulnerability actually is.

Could someone please define this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the category of vulnerability that contains things like [**buffer-overflow vulnerabilities**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#Exploitation).